# Determine WAR context root from MDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, war, glassfish-3

I have a JavaEE ear containing an ejb and war being deployed to GlassFish v3.1.2.2. The war contains a Jersey/Atmosphere application that is using CDI. Within the war, I have an MDB that is asynchronously receiving events it will broadcast using Atmosphere. The message I need to broadcast using Atmosphere needs to includes some links to other resources in the web application.

In order to build those links, like in other places in the code, I would like to use `UriBuilder`. To do so, I need access to the application's deployed context root, so I can invoke `UriBuilder.fromPath(contextRoot)`

This [Java EE 7 article](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv004.htm) implies I can inject a ContextServlet into a CDI bean this way:

```
@Inject ServletContext context;
```

But this does not work for my MDB. I'm also only on JavaEE6 w/ Glassfish v3.

How can I access the `ServletContext` from an MDB hosted in my war?

Comment: You could get the URL from say a context listener in your application and stick that in a place that the MDB can reach too, such as in an EHCache. But if it were me I'd make it as dumb as possible and stick the URL to transmit in a property database table. I don't want to make my MDBs dependent on the web layer, they're two entirely isolated things.

Comment: For the MDBs in my EJB layer, I entirely agree. This MDB lives in web layer, and is handling 'domain events' to publish on the web layer, so I think a dependency on the servlet context is reasonable.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree then. I hope my suggestions are something you can live with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with the following.

1. Installed the [deltaspike servlet module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation.html#servlet-module) since I'm on GlassFish v3.1.2.2 which does not have CDI 1.1 which includes a provider for `ServletContext` out of the box.
2. Followed the MDB piece of [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/integrating_websockets_and_jms_with) to convert my JMS message to a *CDI event* and then observed that CDI event from a pure CDI bean that had the `ServletContext` injected in order to build out the required URLs for the Atmosphere message.